# Capture group inside non-capturing group

Tags: python, regex

I want to do capture two groups, but one is inside a non-capture group. i.e.

```
import re

text = 'column{fields}'
parsed = re.search(r'(\w+)(?:{(\w+)})', text)
parsed.groups() # prints ('column', 'fields')
```

That works, however if my text is only `'column'`, `regex` is NoneType.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make 2nd non-capturing group optional:

```
>>> text = 'column'
>>> parsed = re.search(r'(\w+)(?:{(\w+)})?', text)
>>> parsed.groups()
('column', None)
```

`?` at the end of `(?:{(\w+)})?` will make part after `column` i.e. `(?:{(\w+)})` **optional**.

Comment: I thought that when I was doing `(?:{(\w+)})` I was actually declaring `{(\w+)}` as optional. Why not?

Comment: To make any part optional in regex you need to place `?` after it (as shown in answer).

Comment: yeah, but I though `( ... )?` was the same as `(?: ... )`. In that case, is `(?: ... )?` reduntant?

Comment: No `(?:...)` means a non-capturing group. It is a group that won't be captured and cannot be used in back-reference. It doesn't make it optional.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying